# Can't connect to SQLite DB using Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, database, sqlite, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a problem which I can't solve: I have project on Symfony and I need to connect to database which placed in same directory with project. I used PDOSqlite driver to esteblish connection but I have next problem - PHP returns to me message, that connection is OK, but when I try to get data from DB, I got an error. Also, if I change path to DB on something stupid, PHP anyway tell to me, that connection is good. Try to find solution in Google, but without success.

There is my code:

```
    protected function getDB() {
    $dbRoute = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/Resources/data/db/2016-06-23.sqlite';

    $driver = new PDO\Driver();

    $connect = array(
        'url' => 'sqlite:///'.$dbRoute
    );

    try {
        $db = $driver->connect($connect);
        echo 'Connection esteblished';
        return $db;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Using multiple SQLite entity managers for multiple bundles and databases in test environment](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5wtr/using-multiple-sqlite-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases-in-test-environment) shows how to set them up. (Using multiple MySQL entity managers for multiple bundles and databases)[http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7cpx/using-multiple-mysql-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases] shows how to access EMs in your code for sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony has already a PDO implemented, you don't need to open or close any connection manually.

In you config.yml do you have something like that?

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_sqlite
        path:     "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/data/db/2016-06-23.sqlite"
```

Then you should use doctrine entity manager ([doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html))

EDIT: you can use [multiple entity managers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) if it is not your default connection with [DBAL a simple query](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html)

Comment: Problem is in that that this is just .sqlite file and I need to get all records from one table to array and to compare this array with array getted from xls file. So, I don't need to create Entity or something else - just read database, make query and fetch result

Comment: Due to your advice I'm open my config.yml file and find there an instruction how to connect sqlite base :D So, thanks for your answer - it was useful for me